# Voting every given time JS

Tags: javascript, event-handling, settimeout, voting, event-delegation

I am working on a project of a leaderboard. It is not a real thing, just a demo for learning purposes as I am a newbie.

To the point. The user can click the voting button, which will add one vote, change the info on the button to "thank you for voting" and finally disable all the remaining buttons, because in real world you are usually allowed to vote once a day. It took my some time, but it is worikig fine.

I was wondering if there is an easy way to let the user vote more often, let's say every 10 sec.
The reason I want to allow it is because the content of the leaderboard is JS generated and if a player gets more  votes than others they will go up on the board automatically (and then I can probably practice using localStorage and transition of some sort).

The code for voting function is this:

```
function voting() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.vote-btn').forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      
      button.innerHTML = 'thanks for voting!';
      button.classList.replace(`vote-btn`, 'voted');
      const target = e.target.closest('button');
      const targetData = target.dataset.btnId;
      
      if (targetData === playerPaul) {
        document.getElementById(targetData).innerText = countPaul + 1;
        disableVoting();
      }
```

The if statements go one for all the players.

The voting buttons are disabled:

```
function disableVoting() {
    document.querySelectorAll('.vote-btn').forEach(button => {
      button.disabled = true;
      button.classList.add('no-cursor');
    }) 
}
```

My idea was to add another function to fire up after a given time.
This function would undo the disabeling function and allow voting again.

```
function intervalVoting() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.vote-btn').forEach(button => {
    button.disabled = false;
    button.classList.remove('no-cursor');
    voting();
  })
}
```

I tried adding `setInterval(intervalVoting, 10000)` to disableVoting() like so:

```
function disableVoting() {
    document.querySelectorAll('.vote-btn').forEach(button => {
      button.disabled = true;
      button.classList.add('no-cursor');
      setInterval(intervalVoting, 10000);
    }) 
}
```

What is does it allows to give another vote after 10sec but only on players that havent't been voted on.

Comment: Are you comfortable with the fact that the only true way to disable voting during a time frame would be to handle it server side?

Comment: You should save the time of the vote and then check if enough time passed

Comment: @veelcheck ... Regarding the so far provided sole answer / solution are there any questions left?

Comment: Questions are permanent :) I thought I would go the "compare time route" but than I had to do other stuff. I see you've posted another approach and I am very grateful for all the answers. I think I'll be able to go back to this project next week and we'll see.

Answer (score 0):

Any more easily to refactor implementation would choose an approach which introduces atomar tasks implemented as meaningfully named function statements.

In addition, and depending on the markup, one could choose [event-delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) in order to not having separately to subscribe an own handler function to each vote-button.

One also could drop some css class-names in favor of more generic and expressive selector-based styling-rules.

```js
function updateVoteCount(target) {
  const countValue = parseInt(target.dataset.voteCount, 10) + 1;

  target.dataset.voteCount = countValue;
  target.textContent = countValue;
}

function restoreVoting(target) {
  target.classList.remove('voted');
  target.textContent = target.dataset.btnTextBeforeVote;

  target.disabled = false;
}
function temporarilyDisableVoting(target) {
  target.disabled = true;

  setTimeout(restoreVoting, 10_000, target);
}

function temporarilyDisableAnyListItemVoting(listRoot) {
  listRoot
    .querySelectorAll('.vote-btn')
    .forEach(temporarilyDisableVoting);
}
function handlePlayerListItemVote({ target }) {
  target = target.closest('.vote-btn');

  const listRoot = target && target.closest('.player-list'); 
  if (listRoot !== null) {

    temporarilyDisableAnyListItemVoting(listRoot);

    target.classList.add('voted');
    target.textContent = target.dataset.btnTextAfterVote;

    updateVoteCount(
      target.closest('li').querySelector('[data-vote-count]')
    );
  }
}

document
  .querySelector('.player-list')
  .addEventListener('click', handlePlayerListItemVote);
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
p { margin: 5px 0; }

button.vote-btn:not(:disabled) { cursor: pointer; }
button.vote-btn.voted { background-color: #cf0; }
```

```html
<ul class="player-list">
  <li>
    <p>
      Player Foo - upvotes:
      <span data-vote-count="0">0</span>
    </p>
    <button
      class="vote-btn"
      data-btn-text-after-vote="thanks for voting!"
      data-btn-text-before-vote="feel free to vote"
    >feel free to vote</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>
      Player Bar - upvotes:
      <span data-vote-count="0">0</span>
    </p>
    <button
      class="vote-btn"
      data-btn-text-after-vote="thanks for voting!"
      data-btn-text-before-vote="feel free to vote"
    >feel free to vote</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>
      Player Baz - upvotes:
      <span data-vote-count="0">0</span>
    </p>
    <button
      class="vote-btn"
      data-btn-text-after-vote="thanks for voting!"
      data-btn-text-before-vote="feel free to vote"
    >feel free to vote</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```